# Vuex - How to use function from mapAction within local computed method

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have these `actions` and `getters` defined on my Vuex store. I now want to use them in my local computed properties. How can I? Using `this` with the action name returns this error:

```
"TypeError: this.updatePlan is not a function"
```

This is what I would LIKE to do.

```
computed: {   
...mapGetters([
  'returnShop',
  'returnPlan',
  'returnFulfillmentEnabled'
]),
...mapActions([
  'getShop',
  'updatePlan'
]),
selectPlan: {
  get() {
    this.returnPlan;
  },
  set(value) {
    this.updatePlan(value);
  }
 }
},
```

None of my actions are `async`

For completeness here are my actions

```
  actions: {
    getShop: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      axios.get("/admin/wine_app/shops").then(response => {
        commit('changeShop', response.data);
      }); 
    },
    updatePlan: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('changePlan', payload);
    }
  }
```

And the store IS injected into all components. See here:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount()
  document.body.appendChild(app.$el)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` & `getters` can be merged as `computed properties`

`actions` & `mutations` can be merged as `methods`

then u should use his `maps` as below:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'returnShop',
    'returnPlan',
    'returnFulfillmentEnabled'
  ]),
  selectPlan: {
    get() {
      this.returnPlan;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.updatePlan(value);
    }
  }
},

methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'getShop',
    'updatePlan'
  ])
}
```